# builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to invert the following dictionary:

```
{'Jane Frank': ['Parent Teacher Association'], 'Paul Young': ['Chess 
Club'], 'Zhou Jo': ['McKinsey'], 'Alex Cube': ['Chess Club', 
'Saxophone'], 'Cam Paulson': ['Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan 
Club'], 'Philip O'Donnel': ['Investment Banking Association'], 'Matt 
Damon': ['Parent Teacher Association']}
```

This is what the inverted dictionary should look like:

```
{'Parent Teacher Association': ['Jane Frank', 'Matt Damon'], 'Chess 
Club': ['Paul Young', 'Alex Cube'], 'McKinsey': ['Zhou Jo'], 
'Saxophone': ['Alex Cube'], 'Cooking School':['Cam Paulson']...**etc**
```

I have the following code so far:

```
new_dictionary = {}
    for value in old_dict:
        new_entry = tuple(old_dict[value])
        if not (new_entry in new_dictionary):
           new_dictionary[new_entry] = [value]
        else:
           new_dictionary[new_entry].append(value)
return new_dictionary
```

This code works but it returns a dictionary where the keys are tuples and one of the keys consists of two elements. Example of output follows below:

```
{('Parent Teacher Association',): ['Jane Frank', 'Matt Damon'], ('Chess 
Club',): ['Paul Young'], ('McKinsey',): ['Zhou Jo'], ('Chess Club', 
'Saxophone'): ['Alex Cube'], ('Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan 
 Club'): ['Cam Paulson'], ('Investment Banking Association',): ['Philip 
 O'Donnel']}
```

What's wrong with this output is that each initial value should be a separate key in the new dictionary i.e. Cooking School should be one key and Harry Potter Fan Club should be one key. Furthermore, the keys should simply be strings and not tuples. I'm trying different things, and will keep updating as I make progress. I hope I'm making some sense. Please help. :)

Comment: What line are you getting the error at?

Comment: This is the line where I am getting the error: if not (new_entry in new_dictionary):

Comment: `new_entry` is a list. In 5th line `new_dictionary[new_entry] = [value]` you are trying to use it as a key in dictionary. Lists are unhashable and can't be used as keys in dictionary.

Comment: @AbbyLiu Edited and Undeleted my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47216254/4909087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be using a nested loop, since your list values can have multiple elements. You'd need an entry for each one.

```
o = {}    
for k, V in d.items():
    for v in V:
         o.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

A slightly more performant version would be using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

o = defaultdict(list)
for k, V in d.items():
    for v in V:
         o[v].append(k)
```

Both methods yield:

```
{'Chess Club': ['Alex Cube', 'Paul Young'],
 'Cooking School': ['Cam Paulson'],
 'Harry Potter Fan Club': ['Cam Paulson'],
 'Investment Banking Association': ["Philip O'Donnel"],
 'McKinsey': ['Zhou Jo'],
 'Parent Teacher Association': ['Matt Damon', 'Jane Frank'],
 'Saxophone': ['Alex Cube']}
```

Comment: getting `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: @VanPeer Thanks, should've been `o[v].append(k)`

Answer (score 2):

Lists are mutable, and therefore inappropriate for dictionary keys.

You could, instead, convert the list to an *immutable* sequence (e.g. a tuple, as I use below) and it would work:

```
d = {
    'Jane Frank': ['Parent Teacher Association'],
     'Paul Young': ['Chess Club'],
     'Zhou Jo': ['McKinsey'],
     'Alex Cube': ['Chess Club', 'Saxophone'],
     'Cam Paulson': ['Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan Club'],
     "Philip O'Donnel": ['Investment Banking Association'],
     'Matt Damon': ['Parent Teacher Association']
}

def invert(old_dict):
    new_dictionary = {}
    for value in old_dict:
        new_entry = tuple(old_dict[value])
        if not (new_entry in new_dictionary):
            new_dictionary[new_entry] = [value]
        else:
            new_dictionary[new_entry].append(value)

    return new_dictionary

print(invert(d))
```

Output:

```
{
 ('Parent Teacher Association',): ['Jane Frank', 'Matt Damon'], 
 ('Chess Club',): ['Paul Young'], 
 ('McKinsey',): ['Zhou Jo'], 
 ('Chess Club', 'Saxophone'): ['Alex Cube'], 
 ('Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan Club'): ['Cam Paulson'], 
 ('Investment Banking Association',): ["Philip O'Donnel"]
}
```

Note that, since some of your *values* had multiple list entries, some of your keys will be multiple-entried tuples (e.g. `('Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan Club')`).

If that's not what you're looking for, and instead you want the inverted dictionary to have an entry for *each* value, then you could use strings as keys instead.  If that's what you want, I can post an example of how you might do that as well.

**EDIT**

Since you want to assign the same value to multiple keys when the "old value" is a multi-element list, you could do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    'Jane Frank': ['Parent Teacher Association'],
    'Paul Young': ['Chess Club'],
    'Zhou Jo': ['McKinsey'],
    'Alex Cube': ['Chess Club', 'Saxophone'],
    'Cam Paulson': ['Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan Club'],
    "Philip O'Donnel": ['Investment Banking Association'],
    'Matt Damon': ['Parent Teacher Association']
}

def invert(old_dict):
    new_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for (old_key, old_vals) in old_dict.items():
        # old_val will be new_key
        for old_val in old_vals:
            new_dict[old_val].append(old_key)

    return new_dict

print(invert(d))
```

Output:

```
{
  'Parent Teacher Association': ['Jane Frank', 'Matt Damon'], 
  'Chess Club': ['Paul Young', 'Alex Cube'], 
  'McKinsey': ['Zhou Jo'], 
  'Saxophone': ['Alex Cube'], 
  'Cooking School': ['Cam Paulson'], 
  'Harry Potter Fan Club': ['Cam Paulson'], 
  'Investment Banking Association': ["Philip O'Donnel"]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could, but I need it to return a dictionary where the keys are of type str

Comment: @AbbyLiu so, in your example, the resulting dictionary should have separate keys for "Chess Club" and "Saxophone", both with the value "Alex Cube", correct?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: A `frozenset` would probably be more appropriate than a `tuple`. Unless `d[("Chess Club", "Saxophone")]` is meaningfully distinct from `d[("Saxophone", "Chess Club")]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of another appoach using an intermediate defaultdict.

```
>>> d = {"Jane Frank": ["Parent Teacher Association"], "Paul Young": ["Chess Club"], "Zhou Jo": ["McKinsey"], "Alex Cube": ["Chess Club", "Saxophone"], "Cam Paulson": ["Cooking School", "Harry Potter Fan Club"], "Philip O'Donnel": ["Investment Banking Association"], "Matt Damon": ["Parent Teacher Association"]}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'Alex Cube': ['Chess Club', 'Saxophone'],
 'Cam Paulson': ['Cooking School', 'Harry Potter Fan Club'],
 'Jane Frank': ['Parent Teacher Association'],
 'Matt Damon': ['Parent Teacher Association'],
 'Paul Young': ['Chess Club'],
 "Philip O'Donnel": ['Investment Banking Association'],
 'Zhou Jo': ['McKinsey']}

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> n = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...    for e in v:
...       n[e].append(k)
... 
>>> n2 = {}
>>> n2.update(n)
>>> pprint(n2)
{'Chess Club': ['Paul Young', 'Alex Cube'],
 'Cooking School': ['Cam Paulson'],
 'Harry Potter Fan Club': ['Cam Paulson'],
 'Investment Banking Association': ["Philip O'Donnel"],
 'McKinsey': ['Zhou Jo'],
 'Parent Teacher Association': ['Matt Damon', 'Jane Frank'],
 'Saxophone': ['Alex Cube']}
>>>
```